# POST error 403 trying to use auth token on local storage to access Django view, then display output in React component

Tags: reactjs, django, authentication, axios, request

I want to create a component that displays all the songs that were uploaded by a user. I am trying to do this by sending a POST request, which contains the user's username and the auth token from local storage, to the Django view which will filter out all the songs that were not uploaded by the user. The view should then send the list of the songs back to the component. The issue is that when I click on the page to see the user's songs, I get the POST error 403 forbidden. I suspect the issue is with the auth token because when I use a get request to get all songs from all users, not just one, it works. Here is my song list component

```
function SongList(props) {

    const [songs, setSongs] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.post('/api/songs/', { username: props.username }, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('authToken')}`,
          },
        }).then((response) => {
          setSongs(response.data);
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
      }, []);

    return ( 
        <div>
            {songs.map((song) => (
                <div key={song.id}>
                <h3>{song.name}</h3>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )}
```

Here is my Django view, which worked normally before I added the username filter

```
def getSongs(request):
    username = request.POST.get("username")
    songs = Song.objects.filter(username=username)
    return JsonResponse(list(songs), safe=False)
```

Here is my login form which creates the auth token

```
function LoginForm({ onLogin }) {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        username: '',
        password: '',
    })

    function handleFormSubmission(e){
        e.preventDefault()

        const data = new FormData()
        data.append('username', formData.username)
        data.append('password', formData.password)

        axios.post('/login/', data).then((response) => {
            onLogin(response.data.status)
            localStorage.setItem('authToken', "test");
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }

    function handleInputChange(e) {
        const {name, value} = e.target
        setFormData((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            [name]: value,
        }))
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmission}>
            <input type="text" name="username" value={formData.username} placeholder="Username" onChange={handleInputChange} />
            <input type="password" name="password" value={formData.password} onChange={handleInputChange} />
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    )}
```

The problem likely has to do with the auth token, I am not too familiar with other ways to authenticate users with both the backend and frontend, maybe there is another method rather than the auth token in localstorage that can do this better.